# My simple Regex doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this simple regex that is supposed to match any numbers and '+' signs

```
/^[\d\+]+$/g
```

What it does is this:

```
1  => true
11 => false
11+11 => true
1+1 => false
```

It's driving me nuts!

(I'm using JavaScript, if it matters)

Comment: What are you trying to? What do you want to match and what do you not want to match?

Comment: @bnjmn: But there is a `+` after the character class. This regex *should*  match - there must be some other problem.

Comment: That regex returns `true` when `test`ing it against all of those test cases that you provided... what browser are you running this on?

Comment: @user3195878 It seems to work for us. Could you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow thanks for correcting me, I'll eagerly wait and see :) If he wants just numbers (digit sequences) and *INFIX* plus signs, wouldn't this work (correct me if I'm wrong, again): `/^\d*[\+\d*]*$/g`?

Comment: @pid No... well, yes technically that would work just as well, but it will also match `+`, `123***`, `++274*+*+`, and an empty string.

Comment: I feel like an idiot, you're totally right! `\d` already is a character, class as you've already said before. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some assumptions I did when reproducing your error:

1. You're using the `test()`-method of the `RegExp`-prototype, not the `match()`-method of the `String`-prototype.
2. Your pattern is stored in a variable and you reuse it over multiple calls to the `test()`-method.

At a first glance, the result is somewhat unexpected, but I'll try to explain what is happening.

Your RegExp has the global-Flag set to true. This causes subsequent calls to the `test()`-method to advance past previous matches, as stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test#Description). This essentially means that after your first regular expression is evaluated and a match was found, the index of this match is stored into the `RegExp`-object and the next match will start at that very index, omitting some characters at the beginning. For a deeper explanation, I'd recommend reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results).

This is not really what you want, right? My quick recommendation would be to simply **remove the global-flag**, as you don't really need it from my point of view. If you want to ensure that your regular expression is only matching full strings rather than substrings, use the `^`and `$` metacharacters (as you already did).

---

**EDIT:**

If you really need the global-flag though, try to use the `match()`-method of the `String`-prototype, as it does not advance past previous matches. Instead it uses the advancing feature and captures all matches, resetting the index afterwards.

```
var pattern = /^[\d\+]+$/g;
"1".match(pattern); // => true
"11+11".match(pattern); // => true
"1+1abc".match(pattern); // => false
```

Comment: You had it right the first time; it makes no sense to use the `g` flag with a regex that's anchored at one or both ends.

Comment: Yeah, that was the gotcha. For convenience's sake I put all my test values in an array and looped over it. The g flag was indeed the cuplrit. Thanks!